# How to use InvalidateViews or NotifyDataSetChange?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm relatively new to xamarin. I'm using custom adapter listview. I've been wrapping around my head about this bug.. I'm trying to show a different updated list in my listview. clicking first item (either one of the 3 items)works fine.. but my problem is after clicking the 2nd Item(which might be the ShowAllLuzon or ShowAllMindanao). It doesn't seem to refresh/update my listview and my items in my listview disappears. I saw about InvalidateViews in java and tried InvalidateOptionMenu(); but it doesn't seems to work properly.. or am I using it wrong? should I add it in my Update method customadapter?

my code in action bar

```
else if (id == Resource.Id.ShowAllLuzon) //show LUZON
    {
        List<Mountain> filteredMountains = (from mountain in mMountains
                                            where mountain.Island == 1
                                            orderby mountain.MtName
                                            select mountain).ToList();
        mAdapter.Update(filteredMountains);
        RunOnUiThread(() => mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
    }
else if (id == Resource.Id.ShowAllVisayas) //show Visayas
    {
        List<Mountain> filteredMountains = (from mountain in mMountains
                                            where mountain.Island == 2
                                            orderby mountain.MtName
                                            select mountain).ToList();

        mAdapter.Update(filteredMountains);
        RunOnUiThread(() => mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
    }
else if (id == Resource.Id.ShowAllMindanao) //show Mindanao
    {
        List<Mountain> filteredMountains = (from mountain in mMountains 
                                            where mountain.Island == 3
                                            orderby mountain.MtName
                                            select mountain).ToList();

        mAdapter.Update(filteredMountains);
        InvalidateOptionsMenu(); //where I added InvalidateOptionsMenu
        RunOnUiThread(() => mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
    }
```

I've also tried rearranging my Update method in my CustomAdapter..

here's my Update method in my CustomAdapter..

```
 public  void Update(List<Mountain> mLists)
    {            
        mtList.Clear();
        mtList.AddRange(mLists);
        NotifyDataSetChanged();            
    }
```

been working in this for almost 3 hours.. please any answers would be really much appreciated..

Comment: What class `Update(..)` belong to? Have you tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `mAdapter`?

Comment: my Update class belongs in my CustomAdapter.. Yes I tried it.. but when I click the second Item, it seems that my method is trying to find it in my current list.. so how can I refresh it before calling the method?

Comment: You've called `notifyDataSetChanged` twice. One in `Update()` method & the other right after the call to `Update()` method. I suggest either call it once inside `Update()` or outside `if-then` structure.

Comment: tried removing it didnt work :(